# Show that this class of functions satisfy assumptions of monotone class theorem.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have random variables $X_1,..,X_k$.

Let $\mathcal H$ be the class of bounded functions of the form $F(X_1,..X_k)$ where $F:\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R$ is measurable.

I want to show that this set satisfies the assumptions of the monotone class theorem.
The part I am struggling with is showing that for $f_n\in \mathcal H$ with $f_n \nearrow f $ where $f $ is bounded then $f \in \mathcal H$. I have no idea how to show that this limit is a function of the given random variables , and would appreciate a hint.